# How to use the names_pattern() argument in pivot_longer()?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to use pivot_longer() to rearrange my dataset and I am aware that I can use the names_pattern argument for this.
What I don't fully understand is the syntax (I think?) of this argument.

There are lot of examples online using different symbols like `(.)`, `(.*)`, or `(/)`, `?(.)`, `(.+)` and I don't understand when to use what.

As an example, here are the colnames of my wider dataset:

```
                       "m_Imp", "r_Imp", "t_Imp", "l_Imp", 
                       "m_OD_1", "r_OD_1", "t_OD_1", "l_OD_1", 
                       "m_WS_1", "r_WS_1", "t_WS_1", "l_WS_1", 
                       "m_OD_2", "r_OD_2", "t_OD_2", "l_OD_2",
                       "m_WS_2", "r_WS_2", "t_WS_2", "l_WS_2", 
                       "m_OD_3", "r_OD_3", "t_OD_3", "l_OD_3",
                       "m_WS_3", "r_WS_3", "t_WS_3", "l_WS_3"
```

The first letter represents a numeric variable, the following 2 or 3 letters represent a certain Process Step and the number in the end stands for a Cycle No. So I would like to have my data is the following format:

```
Process_Step   Cycle   m      r     t 
OD               1     0.2    5     6
OD               2     0.3    4     7
OD               3     0.25   2     7
Imp              1     0.3    4     9
Imp              2     0.5    4     7
...
```

The actual data frame is very large, so I hope this example is OK for this question.

Then I tried to use pivot_longer() as follows:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = "m_OD":"l_WS_3",
               names_to = c(".value", "Process_step", "Cycle"),
               names_pattern ="(.)_(..?)_?(.)" )
```

Which almost works, but I get something like this:

```
Process_Step   Cycle   m      r     t 
O                D     0.2    5     6
OD               1     0.2    5     6
OD               2     0.3    4     7
OD               3     0.25   2     7
Im               p     0.3    4     9
Im               p     0.5    4     7
                       0.3    4     9
                       0.5    4     7
...
```

So in some cases the Process Step is mixed up with the Cycle and sometimes empty rows etc.

Can anyone explain how to use the names_pattern argument?

Answer (score 0):

`names_pattern` argument uses regular expression groups, the similar to the ones used by `stringr` and `grep`. For a more complete explanation of how regular expressions work, you can read the documentation ([This guide is quite good](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions)). The short version is, `pivot_longer` matches the name of each column you are pivoting longer, using the pattern, and each set of brackets within the pattern (e.g.`(something)`) creates a group, which is then extracted from the column name, and turned into a variable in a column, which you name in the `names_to` variable. The first group will go to the column named for the first string in `names_to`, the second to the second string, and so on.

Here is what the documentation says:

> `names_pattern` takes the same specification as `extract()`, a regular expression containing matching groups (⁠()⁠).

This is what I mentioned just before.

> If these arguments do not give you enough control, use pivot_longer_spec() to create a spec object and process manually as needed.

This is giving you the option of using `pivot_longer_spec`, a more customisable version of `pivot_longer`

Re: `names_to`, this is what it says:

> If length >1, multiple columns will be created. In this case, one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern` must be supplied to specify how the column names should be split. There are also two additional character values you can take advantage of:
>
> `NA` will discard the corresponding component of the column name.
>
> ".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding values_to entirely.

Here is how I did what you were trying to do (I wasn't able to do it in one go, but it's okay, it's not the end of the world!

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)
n_rows <- 10

df <- tibble(
  m_Imp = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_Imp = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_Imp = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_Imp = rnorm(n_rows),
  m_OD_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_OD_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_OD_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_OD_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  m_WS_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_WS_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_WS_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_WS_1 = rnorm(n_rows),
  m_OD_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_OD_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_OD_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_OD_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  m_WS_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_WS_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_WS_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_WS_2 = rnorm(n_rows),
  m_OD_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_OD_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_OD_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_OD_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  m_WS_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  r_WS_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  t_WS_3 = rnorm(n_rows),
  l_WS_3 = rnorm(n_rows)
)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c(".value", "Process Step"),
               names_pattern = "(.)_(.*)") %>%
  separate(`Process Step`, into = c("Process Step", "Cycle"), sep = "_", fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(Cycle = as.numeric(Cycle))
```